LCP in react app is very high - how to figure out why - has something changed?
I work at a media organization. Our code base is a react app with some additional infrastructure. On Oct 3, our LCP increased greatly - from around 2s to 10+ seconds. We hadn't made major code changes then and we've tried rolling back those changes and yet tools like Treo consistently show these high LCPs.
I have several questions ...

LCP seems challenging to diagnose as the times reported in Treo and Google aren't reproducible locally. Is there a reliable way to test LCP?

How can I identify the root cause of the high LCP?

Did something change with how LCP was measured around October 3rd?

Is it worthwhile to bundle scripts and other potentially render-blocking items?



You can gather your own Web Vitals data from users that visit your site, which includes more details like the element that LCP was based on.
https://web.dev/articles/vitals-field-measurement-best-practices
You can also determine which page types and devices have poor LCPs. It may be one page for mobile users that is pulling down your score.
You could gather even more details. Is it users in a specific country, or with a slow network, or using an older browser.
